# jquery use a var with focus()

Tags: jquery, focus

when I write:

$('#telPro').focus(); //telPro is the id of an input

focus is given to the telPro input.

But if I construct a var like this :

b = "$"+"("+"'"+"#"+"telPro"+"'"+")";

who gives $('#telPro') and write

b.focus();

I get the error : TypeError: b.focus is not a function

Can someone explain me what and btw how can I do.

Thanks for answer

Comment: `b` is a string..

Comment: try $(b).focus()

Comment: Can you please explain your mental process behind constructing `b` like that, rather than just taking the `.focus()` off of what you were already doing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers. The solution gave by BASEER HAIDER JAFRI is the good one and it runs for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.focus()` is not a function on a string.  And `b` is a *string*:

```
b = "$"+"("+"'"+"#"+"telPro"+"'"+")";
```

If you want `b` to be a jQuery object, don't wrap your code in quotes.  Only wrap your *strings* in quotes:

```
b = $("#"+"telPro");
```

Which, of course, is identical to:

```
b = $("#telPro");
```

Strings which contain text which happens to be code are not themselves code.  They're just strings.

(Side note: You *might* be looking for [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).  But you probably *really* shouldn't be.)